# office.js addin when appsource store is deactivated in enterprise

Tags: office-js

I would like to create an **office.js app** for use within my (large) company.
However, **the Microsoft AppStore is deactivated by default** in our MS Office products. So I would not be able to distribute / manage the app this way.

Is it technically possible to host such an Office.js app within the company and only make it accessible within the company? What infrastructure would need to exist to make that possible?

Does one host the app on an internal Web server?
How does one make the app available to the Office products if one cannot use the store?
Unfortunately, all the tutorials and documentations I found relied on the MS app store.

(I am obviously not asking about the IT security rules within the company. I would let my app get approved by IT security. The question is of technical nature only.)

Comment: Maybe this is the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog

Comment: Be aware of the limitations of Officejs! E.g. when using Office2013 the add-in is rendered in a IE11 process which is causing me enormous troubles with longer base64 strings (trying to download the attachments), but if a file is bigger then 7mB IE11 throws an error saying "Not enough storage to perform the operation".

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like [Centralized deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) could be used in this scenario.

The Office 365 admin center makes it easy for an administrator to deploy Office Add-ins to users and groups within their organization. Add-ins deployed via the admin center are available to users in their Office applications right away, with no client configuration required. You can use Centralized Deployment to deploy internal add-ins as well as add-ins provided by ISVs.

Comment: Exactly what we do.